# Why is Unit an Anyval ? What does it mean semantically?

Tags: scala

In Scala, why is Unit an Anyval ? What does it mean semantically ? Why not an Any or Anyref?

Semantically what is the difference and what is the rational behind that choice?

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a Unit variable with value `null`.

However, Unit can be boxed in the usual sense:

```
scala> def f[A](a: A) = 42
f: [A](a: A)Int

scala> f(())
res0: Int = 42

scala> :javap -pv -
[snip]
        12: getstatic     #41                 // Field scala/runtime/BoxedUnit.UNIT:Lscala/runtime/BoxedUnit;
        15: invokevirtual #45                 // Method $line3/$read$$iw$$iw$.f:(Ljava/lang/Object;)I
```

Similarly,

```
scala> var x: Unit = _
x: Unit = ()
```

is really `BoxedUnit.UNIT` under the hood.

The "unboxed" type `BoxedUnit.TYPE` is `Void.TYPE`.

Comment: What does this have to do with Any, AnyRef or AnyVal? It's clear Unit has to be a bottom type, but why *that one*?

Comment: @adamnfish Unit is not a bottom anything. It's like Int, except it has only one value, `()`. It can't have `null` as a value (like Int can't be `null`), so it can't be a supertype of `Null`. `typeOf[Nothing] <:< typeOf[Unit]`.

Comment: so is that the difference between AnyVal and AnyRef? Only one of them can be nulled?

Comment: @adamnfish You don't have to ask me. `typeOf[Null] <:< typeOf[AnyVal]` will tell you.

Comment: Thanks, although `error: not found: value typeOf`. I guess I mean is that the only difference between `AnyVal` and `AnyRef`? I've long struggled to find a clear description of why those concepts are visible in Scala.

Comment: @adamnfish `import reflect.runtime._, universe._`. Instead of struggling, ask on gitter or google group.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear described into scala docs:

> .. There is only one value of type Unit, `()`, and it is not represented by any object in the underlying runtime system. A method with return type `Unit` is analogous to a Java method which is declared `void`.

Comment: I'm not sure how that qualifies as pretty clear, since it makes no mention of `Any`, `AnyVal` or `AnyRef`?

Comment: That was the sentence before. To highlight that 1) `There is only one value of type` 2) `not represented by any object`. Exactly this can achived by making `Unit extends AnyVal`